# When i use domain and page name its redirecting to another folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

This is the URL of my website http://www.harimaumalaysia.my/ when i access through this url i can see my website with out error.

but when i use this URL http://www.harimaumalaysia.my/index.php Its redirecting to this URL www.harimaumalaysia.my/demo1.

how come this is happening while using index.php I changed my website url in database and permalinks but it didn't solved my problem can anyone help me out of this here is my ht-access file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: For me its opening  http://www.harimaumalaysia.my/index.php correctly . not redirecting to demo page. Try to open after clearing all cache in your browser

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. i would like to ask one more thing if you check this url: http://www.harimaumalaysia.my/  it will show html page. but you access the this url: http://www.harimaumalaysia.my/index.php i would like to load index.php how can i do that do you have any idea?

Comment: Use htaccess redirect rule. You will get lot of examples and documents on net

Answer (score 0):

Set rewrite rule for index file like below.

```
       <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteRule ^(css|editor|editordocs|images|js|sysimgdocs)/.*$ - [PT]
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          RewriteRule . index.php
      </IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried that one also not working. If u see the top ht-access file code that's how i'm using rewrite rule.

Comment: replace your code with mine code and let me know it's working or not.